# Change value of variable with a pointer?

Tags: c

I am new with pointers and I am trying to create a function that changes value of variable **a** to variable **b**, and the value of variable **b** to variable **a**.

I think I have everything right except the function. In the function I am trying to make the value of pointer **a** (***a**) and assign it to the value pointer **b** has, and vice verca. However my output is "a is now y and b is now y".

Is this because when I assign ***a** to **b**, **b** will get ***a**'s value which just changed to an **y**?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void change(char* a, char* b)
{
    *a = b;
    *b = a;
}

int main(void)
{

    char a = 'x';
    char b = 'y';


    printf("a is now %c and b is now %c\n", a, b); 

    change(&a, &b);

    printf("a is now %c and b is now %c\n", a, b); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: when you do : *a = b you will have a = 'y' then *b = a you will have b = 'y'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `change` function is wrong:

```
void change(char* a, char* b)
{
    char temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

First make a temporary variable - copy it in a temp variable, then swap the value. This line is UB:

```
*a = b;
*b = a;
```

You are trying to store a pointer's value in a char.

Comment: It's funny that all examples of the swap function use a variable named `temp` for the temporary copying. It's like it wasn't going to work if you don't put that name to that variable :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your first assignment overwrites the value that is needed in the second one.

The solution is to use some temporary storage to hold the one of the variable values during the swap:

```
void change(char *a, char *b)
{
  const char old_a = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = old_a;
}
```

There is also a trick you can do to go around this (using bitwise XOR), but it's scary so ignore it at this point.